# counting number of times a key is in map

Tags: list, dictionary, haskell

I have the following code:

```
type Film = (Fan, Title, Review)
filmRating :: [Film] -> [(Fan, Int)]
filmRating l = undefined
```

I want to be able to give a list:

[("fan1", "film1", 3), ("fan1", "film2", 3), ("fan3", "film1", 5), ("fan4", "film3", 8)]

Now the function wants me to outout a list with how many films a fan watched. so with the list above, I should get:

[("fan1", 2). ("fan3", 1), ("fan4", 1)]

I need to use map and set so I ended up with this

```
titlesFan :: (Ord k, Ord a) => [(k, a, c)] -> [(k, [a])]
titlesFan l = Map.fromListWith (++) [(f, [t]) | (f, t, _) <- l]
```

and I can't seem to be able to get the length as it just gives 1

Comment: Running `titlesFan` on your input results in `[("fan1",["film2","film1"]),("fan3",["film1"]),("fan4",["film3"])]`. How exactly are you calling `length` on that to get `1`?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Probably `map length`...

Answer (score 2):

The `length` of a pair is always 1<sup>*</sup>:

```
> length (False, "abc")
1
```

Probably this is what's happening to you, accidentally. Instead, ask for the `length` of the second part of the tuple:

```
> length . snd $ (False, "abc")
3
```

<sup>*</sup> If you think of `(Bool, String)` as being a container of `String`s, it's clear that there's always exactly one `String` in that container, which justifies this result. Though of course whether or not you consider the thought of `(Bool, String)` being a container of `String`s to be justified is a different thing entirely...

Comment: but thing is i want something like (False, 3)

Comment: @Montye Once you know what you're doing wrong, I think you can figure out how to do it right. I believe in you.